# Error In Using --windowed or --noconsole in PyInstaller

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, kivy-language, kivymd

I Am Working On A Project That I Need To Make A EXE File.

I Have To Mention That My Python File Is Using Kivy And Kivymd Modules

But When I Use PyInstaller It Makes The EXE File Succussfully:

`PyInstaller --onefile --widnowed --noconsole file.py`

But When I Run The EXE File, A Small Window Opens And Says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1113, in emit

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: Have you tried configuring the logger to output to a file?

Comment: what is it? what do you mean?

Comment: See the logging [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file).